# Interfacing Arduino nano ,adxl335 ,nrf24l01

Tags: sensors, arduino-nano, nrf24l01+

I'm trying to make a project with this conection diagram [image] but I don't think it's correct , and my adxl sensor died . Can you help me with a modified one ?

Comment: the Nano ground is not connected to the battery ground

Comment: what do you need help with? ... you said nothing about any problems that you are having ... `adxl sensor died` does not mean anything ... description of what you observed would mean something

Comment: I want to connect that transceiver and accelerometer to arduino nano and I don't know how to make the connections correctly , I used that picture and destroyed my adxl sensor.Battery's -, accelerometer and tranceiver should all be connected  to arduino's ground and adxl's VCC should be connected to arduino's 3V3 ?

Comment: did you get the solution i have the same project